# Plotly backend with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python

Hi I would like to do multiple graph (2 indeed) with pandas / backend Plotly.
I don't know how to proceed.
and what are the main option to change the size of my graph (it seems that figsize does not work) ? the color ?

I did something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

f1 = data.plot(y=['vl','bench'], title='Fonds vs Bench')
f2 = data.plot(y='aum', title='AuM du fonds')

f1.show(figsize=(8,5))
f2.show(figsize=(8,5))
```

and would like something equivalent of (without Plotly backend):

```
f, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8,5), sharex=True)

data.plot(y=['vl', 'bench'], title='Fonds vs Bench', ax=ax1)
data.plot(y='aum', title='AuM du fonds',ax=ax2);
```

Comment: Did you try `data.plot(..., figsize=(8, 5))`?

Comment: I got an error : TypeError: line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'figsize'

Answer (score 0):

you can use the subplot method to create multiple subplots in a single figure. Also, you can use the update_layout method to change the size of the figure and the update_traces method to change the color of the traces.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# set Plotly as the backend for pandas
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

# create a figure with two subplots
fig = px.subplot(rows=2, cols=1)

# add the first plot to the first subplot
fig.add_trace(px.line(data, x=data.index, y='vl', name='vl'))
fig.add_trace(px.line(data, x=data.index, y='bench', name='bench'))
fig.update_layout(title_text='Fonds vs Bench')

# add the second plot to the second subplot
fig.add_trace(px.line(data, x=data.index, y='aum', name='aum'))
fig.update_layout(title_text='AuM du fonds', row=2, col=1)

# change the size of the figure
fig.update_layout(width=800, height=500)

# change the color of one of the traces
fig.update_traces(line=dict(color='red'), selector=dict(name='vl'))

# show the figure
fig.show()
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Reference: https://plotly.com/python/

Comment: i have an error message when I tried your solution which was: AttributeError: module 'plotly.express' has no attribute 'subplot'

Answer (score 0):

When creating a graph from Pandas using plotly, if you want to customize the content of the graph, you can use plotly to modify it. To modify the graph size, specify the width and height in pixels. If the desired size is 8 inches wide by 5 inches high, matplotlib's default dpi is 100 pixels, so we specified 800 pixels and 500 pixels.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

np.random.seed(20220212)

data = pd.DataFrame({'vl': np.random.randint(0,25,5),
                   'bench': np.random.randint(25,50,5),
                   'aum': np.random.randint(50,75,5)})

f1 = data.plot(y=['vl','bench'], title='Fonds vs Bench')
f2 = data.plot(y=['aum'], title='AuM du fonds')

f1.update_layout(autosize=False, width=800, height=500)
f2.update_layout(autosize=False, width=800, height=500)

f1.show()
f2.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use matplotlib and seaborn:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))
sns.boxplot(x = 'bedrooms', y = 'price', data = dataset_df)
```

if you want two and more plot use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20, 15))
```

And use ax=ax[0,1]